# Loop on a multidimensional array JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I get a json answer from a PHP:

```
[{"id":"28","PersonnelNumber":"dsam21","email":"xxx@xxx.com","dokjogcsoport":"ad 
min","szerzjogcsoport":"admin","aktiv":"1"},{"brand_kod":"AGI"}]
```

and I try to use `$.each` to loop on it, but I can't get back the *value of* `brand_kod`.

```
$.each(answer, function(idx,item)
{
 //some code
}
```

So how can I get back this value? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a string (JSON) or array of objects?

Comment: My crystal ball says: Your PHP sending the JSON does not set the `Content-Type` header properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop you've written will iterate over each object in the array of objects. You can iterate over the objects values and keys with an inner loop:

```js
answer = [{"id":"28","PersonnelNumber":"dsam21","email":"xxx@xxx.com","dokjogcsoport":"admin","szerzjogcsoport":"admin","aktiv":"1"},{"brand_kod":"AGI"}]

$.each(answer, function(idx, item) {
    console.group(idx);
    for (key in item) {
        console.log(key, item[key]);
    }
    console.groupEnd(idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```